# Draw a Tree Structure with Polymer With Dynamic Binding

Tags: html, css, treeview, polymer, polymer-1.0

Im developing a web application with Polymer, which contains a module, where we want to show a family structure as a tree. Hovering on each node should highlight the full path to that tree. I have a JSON as follows.

[image]

This JSON contains hierarchy of a family (I have removed some nodes for the sake of simplicity).

I want the tree like

[image]

and what i have till now is:

[image]

As you can see, i couldn't find a way to draw the links.

The code i used to create this view is as follows:

family-tree.html

```
<dom-module id="family-tree">
<style>
    :host {
        display: block;
    }      
</style>
<template>
    <call-api auto file="mockdata.json" on-response="handleResponse" 
        last-response="{{familyInfo}}" handle-as="json"></call-api>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{familyInfo.plugin}}">
        <div class="tree">
            <div class="node">
                <a href="#">{{item.id}}</a>
            </div>
            <tree-wrapper family-hierarchy="{{item.children}}"></tree-wrapper>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Polymer(
        {

         is: 'family-tree',
        properties: {
            familyInfo: {
                type: Object,
                notify: true
            },

        }
    });

and tree-wrapper.html:

```
<dom-module id="tree-wrapper">
<style>
    :host {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<template>
    <div class="item">
        <ul>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[familyHeirarchy]]">
                <li>
                    <div class="node">{{item.id}}</div>
                    <tree-wrapper family-heirarchy="{{item.children}}"></tree-wrapper>
                </li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Polymer(
        {
        is: 'tree-wrapper',

        properties: {
            familyHeirarchy: {
                type: Array,
                value: [],
            }
        },

    });

and in my index.html

This will recursively bind and generate the nodes. Can any one tell me how to draw the links as shown in image?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a plunker I can probably help out with the css.

Comment: @Vishnu Please post your answer here for other users to find it.